# How can I add implicit dependencies to a dependency in Python Poetry?

Tags: python, dependencies, python-poetry

My project depends on a package that I do not maintain: PackageA. PackageA depends on PackageB but does not explicitly specify PackageB as a dependency in its setup.py file.

Ideally, the PackageA maintainer would explicitly add PackageB as a dependency, but I can't control that.

I could simply `poetry add PackageB` to my project but then I would be taking a dependency on PackageB, when really I only want to depend on PackageA.

I attempted to manually modify the `[package.dependencies]` for PackageA in the poetry.lock file to add `PackageB = *` but Poetry began complaining. That also seems like a bit of a hack as the dependency relationship is still not modelled anywhere in the pyproject file.

Is there a way that I can tell Poetry that I want to take a dependency on PackageA but that PackageA also has a dependency on PackageB?

Comment: by depending on packageA are you not also depending on packageB (considering you lack the ability to affect the packageA requirements to force it to depend on that?) ... or maybe you might find it more appropriate to add it to the `extras` section ... but that just seems like an extra step to me...

Comment: I considered extras, but it's not really an extra. Yes it gets a bit philosophical, I depend on PackageB because without it, PackageA doesn't work. Pragmatically though, I would like to model my dependencies such that if/when I choose to remove my dependency on PackageA, that the PackageB dependency would be removed along with it (assuming none of my other dependencies depend on PackageB).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems like some extra work to me but i guess you could do

```
[tool.poetry.group.packageA]
optional = true

[tool.poetry.group.packageA.dependencies]
packageA = "^1.3.4"
packageB = "^1.2.3"
```

then install with `poetry install --with packageA`

or remove the `optional=true` flag that i left in like a dummy and it will work just as you expect :P I think (thanks @Nathan)

or you could add it to the `extras` section

```
[tool.poetry.extras]
packageA = ["packageA","packageB"]
```

and install with `poetry install -E packageA`

but if it was me i would just add it to my main dependencies

Comment: If I understand @Nathan correctly, their dependency on packageA isn't optional.

Comment: so he would always have to do `--with` as long as that dependency existed ... as i said i would probably just add it to my dependencies... and add a note or something so i would remember to delete it if i ever got rid of it ... but i feel these are pretty much the only options short of forking A and maintaining it the first two meet what i think is the spirit of the question but the last is what i would do ... but maybe there is a better way)

Comment: @Joran it's an interesting idea to use a package group and from my understanding of the documentation, if I don't specify that the group is optional then it will be installed along with the rest of my "main" dependencies, so I could keep PackageA and PackageB in their own group so that it becomes obvious that I can remove PackageB once PackageA is no longer needed, but not need to do anything outside of "poetry install" to get them included in the venv. If there is no better way, I will mark this as the answer.

Comment: thats a great point (to be fair i just copied and pasted the example from their docs but that makes a lot of sense)

Comment: thanks @Nathan ... I misunderstood what you were saying at first ... you are correct :P

Comment: Marked as the answer, it doesn't appear we can do better this in Poetry at this stage. Simple enough to do with poetry CLI, too. `poetry add --group PackageA PackageA PackageB`